# Link in warning about reputation limit does not lead to Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, asking-questions, meta

When one has less than 5 reputation, this warning comes up when attempting to ask a question on MSO:

[image]

It's kind of hard to see, but I hovered on the link to my only question on Stack Overflow, and the URL is displayed at the bottom left corner. However, the link is wrong. That question is on Stack Overflow, and the link shows the question to be on MSO. Therefore, when I click on the question, it leads me to a "Page Not Found" on MSO.

This is my actual [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50877880/xcode-quick-help-isnt-showing-up).

Comment: Nice Catch. I assume that you need to include a link to your [so] question, right?

Comment: I did, at the very bottom("This is my actual question").

Comment: Yeah. My question was if this was a requirement to post this question.

Comment: Probably someone was trying to be clever by removing the would-be redundant domain component of an absolute URI, because someone before had not bothered to write a documenting code comment explaining that the hard-coded "//stackoverflow.com" prefix is deliberate and required, and neither individual was thinking clearly/sober at the time.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Not really. I just thought it would be helpful to prove my point.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the bug you observed, the behavior of the list was such that if you clicked anywhere on an entry *other than* the link to the post it would fill out the form and submit it, allowing you to ask a question... If you clicked *on* the link, it would simultaneously try to submit the form and navigate to the (broken) link... Likely resulting in a 404 page.

I've tried to address both issues:

1. Links now point to the right site.
2. Clicking *on* the link just fills in the form but neither submits it nor navigates to the question; you can open the question in a new tab/window to view it.
3. Clicking *next to* the link fills in the form and submits it.
4. There's a title-tip that reads "ask about this post" if you hover over the entry.

Hopefully this will be somewhat less confusing for people trying to ask about their posts here.